# How to know if AVCaptureDevice.SystemUserInterface.videoEffects are supported for the current device?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturedevice, video-effects

Calling [AVCaptureDevice.showSystemUserInterface(.videoEffects)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/systemuserinterface) on an unsupported device or without an active video feed can result in a faulty screen.

How to programatically determinate if the current device supports videoEffects at all ?

I found which devices support Depth Control on [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/aside/ipha86ca71fc/16.0/ios/16.0) but I hardcoding isn't the best solution.

The faulty screen:
[image]

The correct screen:
[image]